# Java concurrency: weird output

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm fooling around with Java threads and I wrote this little program that creates several threads and runs them. In each thread a value is incremented multiple times. I used ThreadLocal class so that there's no contention for resources.

Source:

```
class MyValueHolder {

    public static ThreadLocal<Integer> value = new ThreadLocal<Integer>()
    {
        protected Integer initialValue() {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    public static void increment() {
        value.set(value.get() + 1);
    }

    public static Integer get() {
        return value.get();
    }
}

class MyTask implements Runnable {

    public static int counter;

    public MyTask() {
        counter++;
    }

    public void run() {

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            MyValueHolder.increment();
        }
        System.out.println("MyTask " + counter + ", Value " + MyValueHolder.get());
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            es.execute(new MyTask());
        }

        es.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

After completion the output is most of the time this:

```
MyTask 5, Value 100
MyTask 5, Value 100
MyTask 5, Value 100
MyTask 5, Value 100
MyTask 5, Value 100
```

Which is what I'd expect to see.

However, sometimes I get something like this:

```
MyTask 2, Value 100
MyTask 4, Value 200
MyTask 5, Value 300
MyTask 5, Value 100
MyTask 5, Value 100
```

Now this is confusing. Why do the values differ even though each task does absolutely the same thing?

Comment: The order in which threads run is **not** guaranteed to be the order in which they were started. If your threads need to run in a particular order, use `wait`/`notify`, or a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CachedThreadPoolExecutor reuses threads if a `Runnable` finishes before you have added all `Runnable`s. If this happens the `ThreadLocal` of that thread will also be reused.

Answer (score 1):

Like stated above, ThreadLocal is being reused.

For counter, use AtomicInteger instead  and set an initial value.
counter++ is not an atomic operation, its two operations and is not thread safe.

Comment: The `counter` is currently not problematic, since it's value is incremented within the constructor - and the constructor is only called from the main method.

Comment: sorry, you are clearly right, the counter is printing incorrect numbers because the thread's run method is finished before all the constructors are called.

Answer (score 0):

threads will keep running while you get an output you should wait for them to finish you can try isAlive(); with the threads